# Clustered index key length warning on varchar(120)?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing, sql-server-2012, indexed-views

So today i have been doing some optimization creating some indexed views etc.
and I came across this warning

> Warning! The maximum key length for a clustered index is 900 bytes. The index 'IX_...' has maximum length of 8004 bytes. For some combination of large values, the insert/update operation will fail.

The index is

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_.. ON  [aView] ([id], [type])
```

The view is

```
CREATE VIEW aView
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS 
SELECT Id, Replace(Replace([aField],'....',''),'....','') AS [Type], COUNT_BIG(*) AS DistinctTotal
FROM .....
INNER JOIN........
```

Id is an INT

aField in the physical table is a VARCHAR(120)

So the maximum key length for the index would be 120+4 bytes would it not?

Why am i seeing this warning?

Is it valid?

Comment: what is the size of id,type

Comment: Please try creating an simple example ,so that we can test it

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql INT is 4 bytes and as stated type is < 120 bytes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For *your* specific situation, analyzing all inputs to your `REPLACE` calls, we can see that they can only ever leave the string the same length or smaller.

But *in general*, `REPLACE` can in theory return a `varchar(8000)` even if one of its inputs was only a `varchar(120)`. SQL Server doesn't perform a complex analysis here - it sees the `replace` and assumes a return type of `varchar(8000)`.

Since we know it will never exceed 120 characters after all replacements, add an explicit `CONVERT(varchar(120),<existing replaces>)` wrapper around the expression.

Comment: Thanks, I had a sneaking suspicion that's what was happening but couldn't easily find an answer so asked the SO :)